# Шифрование строки функцией Эйлера. Перевод решения из Pascal на C#

Tags: c#, pascal

Помогите перевести правильно из Pascal в C#
пробовал сам но возникли проблемы

Код на Pascal

```pascal
var
   p, q, r, fr, e, d, m, c, s: int64;
   z:string;
   i:longint; // Затрудняюсь перевести тут 
   a:array of int64;

function TPower(a,b,n: int64):int64; // Затрудняюсь перевести тут 
   Var i,k: int64;
   begin
      k:=1; for i:=1 to b do k:=(k*a) mod n;
      TPower:=k; // Затрудняюсь перевести тут 
   end;
          
function Inverse(a, n: int64): int64;
   var
      i: int64;
   begin
      for i := 1 to N - 1 do if (a * i) mod N = 1 then break;
      Inverse := i; // Затрудняюсь перевести тут 
      writeln('Закрытый ключ - ', i);
   end;
         
begin
   Writeln('Введите p = ');
   Readln(p);
   Writeln('Введите q = ');
   Readln(q); 
   r := p * q;
   Writeln('Произведение двух простых чисел p и q равно r = ', r);
   fr := (p - 1) * (q - 1);
   Writeln('функция Эйлера f(r) = ', fr);
   Writeln('Введите открытый ключ e < fr, e = ');
   Readln(e);
   d := Inverse(e, fr);
   Writeln('Введите строку: ');readln(z);
   SetLength(a,length(z));
   Writeln('Зашифрованное сообщение: ');
   for i:=1 to length(z) do begin
      m:=ord(z[i]); // Затрудняюсь перевести тут 
      a[i-1] :=  TPower(m,e,r); // Затрудняюсь перевести тут 
      Write(a[i-1],' '); // Затрудняюсь перевести тут 
   end;
   writeln;
   z:='';
   for i:=0 to length(a)-1 do
      z:=z+chr(TPower(a[i],d,r));
   writeln('Расшифрованное сообщение: ',z)  
end.
```

Код на С# не рабочий, так как не смог правильно перевести

```cs
static int TPower(int a, int b,int n)
{
    int k = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < b; i++)
    {
        k = (k * a) % n;
    }
    return k;
}
    
static int Inverse(int a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        if ((a*i)% n ==1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($" Закрытый ключ { i }");
    return i;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int p, q, n, fr, e, d, m, c, s;
    string z;
    int[] Myarr;
    Console.WriteLine("Введите p");
    p = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Введите q");
    q = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    n = p * q;
    Console.WriteLine($" Произведение двух простых чисел равно { n }");
    fr = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
    Console.WriteLine($"Фукция эелера равна {fr} ");
    Console.WriteLine("Введите открытый ключ");
    e = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    d = Inverse(e, fr);
    Console.WriteLine("Введите строку");
    z = Console.ReadLine();// НЕ ЗНАЮ ПРАВИЛЬНО ИЛИ НЕТ
    char[] Myarr = z.ToCharArray(); // НЕ ЗНАЮ ПРАВИЛЬНО ИЛИ НЕТ
    Console.WriteLine("Зашифрованное сообщение");
    for (int i = 1; i < z.Length; i++)
    {
        m = z.IndexOfAny[i];
        a[i - 1] = TPower(m, e, n);
        Console.Write(a[i-1]+" ");
    }
    z = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
    
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Расшифреванное сообщение"+z);
    Console.ReadLine()
}
```

Comment: я пробовал переводить, и вот что получилось, но в некоторых местах возникает ошибка со строкой, а в некоторых, я не понимаю как на С# gthtdtcnb

Comment: вот мой ПОЛУпереведенный код

Comment: Ну и в чём проблема? Вы не знаете какую-то конкретную конструкцию, которую надо перевести? Или с чем проблема?

Comment: Я указал где у меня вопросы

Comment: `TPower:=k; // Затрудняюсь перевести тут`  обычно переводится как `return k`

Comment: `function TPower(a,b,n: int64):int64; // Затрудняюсь перевести тут ` правильно перевели как `int TPower(int a, int b,int n)`, в чём затруднения?

Comment: у меня очень большая проблема в самом конце, где нужно работать со строкой

Comment: @минусующие, вы так просто за компанию минусуете ("все минусуют и я минусую"), или сообщите все-таки автору, как ему надо исправить вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое важное отличие Pascal от C# здесь - это то что индексация массивов начинается не с 1, а с 0.

Далее вам не хватило знания о том, что есть неяное и явное преобразование между `char` и `int`. Например получение кода символа.

```cs
char c = 'A';
int a = (int)c; // явное преобразование
int a = c; // неявное преобразование
```

В обратном направлении существует только явное преобразование.

При этом зашифрованный массив в Pascal и C# могут отличаться, потому что просто используются разные таблицы символов. В Pascal используется DOS кодировка CP866 (ASCII с руссифицированным шрифтом), в C# для строк и символов используется UTF-16. При желании вы можете в C# использовать и ASCII, но потеряете возможность использовать кириллицу.

Можно использовать и более приближенную к ASCII кодировку, поддерживающую русский - UTF-8 (коды латинских символов в ASCII и UTF-8 совпадают). `string` при этом можно преобразовать в последовательность байт так.

```cs
string text = "Привет, мир!";
byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

И далее работать с байтовым массивом немного доработав методы шифрования. Обратно преобразовать можно вот так:

```cs
string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array);
```

Так как **P**, **N** и отрытый ключ - простые числа, я написал простой генератор простых числел, чтобы вам можно было проще поэкспериментировать.

```cs
private static IEnumerable<int> GetPrimeNumbers(int length)
{
    bool[] states = new bool[length];
    for (int i = 2; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (!states[i])
        {
            for (int j = i * 2; j < length; j += i)
                states[j] = true;
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}

static int TPower(int a, int b, int n)
{
    int k = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        k = k * a % n;
    }
    return k;
}

static int Inverse(int a, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a * i % n == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Закрытый ключ: i = {i}");
    return i;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Простые числа");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", GetPrimeNumbers(100)));

    Console.Write("Введите p (простое число): ");
    int p = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Введите n (простое число): ");
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int r = p * n;
    Console.WriteLine($"Произведение двух простых чисел p и n: r = {r}");
    int fr = (p - 1) * (n - 1);
    Console.WriteLine($"Функция Эйлера: f(r) = {fr}");
    Console.Write("Введите открытый ключ (простое число): ");
    int e = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int d = Inverse(e, fr);
    Console.Write("Введите строку: ");
    string z = Console.ReadLine();
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(z);
    int[] a = new int[bytes.Length];
    Console.WriteLine("Зашифрованное сообщение");
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        int m = bytes[i];
        a[i] = TPower(m, e, r);
        Console.Write(a[i] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    byte[] s = new byte[bytes.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        s[i] = (byte)TPower(a[i], d, r);
    }
    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(s);
    Console.WriteLine("Расшифрованное сообщение: " + result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Простые числа
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97
Введите p (простое число): 29
Введите n (простое число): 67
Произведение двух простых чисел p и n: r = 1943
Функция Эйлера: f(r) = 1848
Введите открытый ключ (простое число): 73
Закрытый ключ: i = 481
Введите строку: Привет, мир!
Зашифрованное сообщение
850 1751 1057 1665 850 1755 850 586 850 227 1057 98 1323 1336 850 1606 850 1755 1057 1665 1195
Расшифрованное сообщение: Привет, мир!
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!!!

Comment: Но почему при использовании одних чисел все работает хорошо, а при других выдает вот так

Comment: Простые числа
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97
Введите p (простое число): 7
Введите n (простое число): 2
Произведение двух простых чисел p и n: r = 14
Функция Эйлера: f(r) = 6
Введите открытый ключ (простое число): 5
Закрытый ключ: i = 5
Введите строку: Спасибо!!!
Зашифрованное сообщение
10 7 10 11 10 8 13 5 10 4 10 11 10 8 3 3 3
♥♀☻♀   ♣♣♣нное сообщение: ♀♀    ♀

Comment: @HOBUCHOK к сожалению, я не вникал глубоко в реализацию того, что написано на паскале, если только немного почитал Википедию. Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, надо разобраться с теорией. Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его галочкой, она расположена слева от ответа.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо вам, очень помогли

Comment: @минусующий Ставишь минус - напиши, зачем это тебе, не бойся, я не кусаюсь и в ответ не минусую. Если есть тому причина - давай вместе разберемся.