# Найти простые числа C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет друзья.
Ищу простые числа от -100 до 100.
Не выводит отрицательные.
Все хочу сделать без функции просто за 2 цикла.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = -100, b = 100;
            for (int i = a; i < b; i++)
            {
                for (int x = 2; x <= i/2; x++)
                {
      
                     if (i%x!=0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Простые числа по определению только положительные. Хотя в принципе вы можете выводить все положительные простые со знаком минус.

Comment: Я сейчас посмотрел результат начинает вроде правильно 5,7 а дальше просто все по порядку. Подскажите где ошибка? Я вроде сделал все правильно

Comment: Простые числа - это 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13... То есть начинать должно с двух

Comment: Ошибка в том, что вы проверяете, делится ли число i на два, после чего сразу выходите из проверки. Можно завести специальную переменную `bool is_prime = true` вне цикла, чтобы написать вместо вашего условия такое: `if (i % x == 0) { is_prime = false; break; }`. Далее после цикла проверки, если is_prime еще true, то вывести число i.

Comment: Вот здесь еще пример другого интересного алгоритма поиска простых чисел https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1235404/373567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простыми числами называют такие ***натуральные*** числа ***больше единицы***, которые имеют только ***два делителя: единицу и само себя***.

```
for (int num = a; num < b; ++num)
{
    if (num == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num);
        continue;
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0 || num <= 1) continue;
    bool is_prime = true;
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= num; i += 2)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            is_prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (is_prime) Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```